# code to search numbers in an array not working for numbers not present in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, search

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//searching using linear search

int linear_search(int arr[], int n, int key){                 //time complexity - order(n)

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==key)
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}


//searching using binary search

int binary_search(int arr[], int n, int key){                 //time complexity-nlog(n) sorted array                                       

    int start=0, end=n-1;
    int middle = (start+end)/2;
    while(start<=end)
    {
        if(arr[middle] == key)
        return middle;
        else if(arr[middle] < key)
        start = middle + 1;
        else if(arr[middle] > key)
        end = middle -1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int n,key;
    cout<<"enter total elements \n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"enter array elements \n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    cout<<"enter number you wanna findd \n";
    cin>>key;

    int key1 = linear_search(arr, n, key);
    int key2 = binary_search(arr, n, key);
```

// I think this part might have a problem, but I cannot figure out what because this is such a simple code which according to me has no mistakes, but it still isn't working properly.

```
    if(key1 != -1)
    cout<<"The number "<<key<< " is found by linear search at position "<<(key1 +1)<<endl;
    else{
    cout<<"key not foound"<<endl;}

    if(key2 != -1)
    cout<<"The number "<<key<< " is found by binary search at position "<<(key2 +1)<<endl;
    else{
    cout<<"key not found";}
    return 0;

}
```

I was writing this code to search a number in an array using both linear and binary search. This code seems to work fine to find numbers that exist in the array, but it does not work for numbers that are not present in the array.

Comment: *"which according to me has no mistakes, but it still isn't working properly."* -- are you really going to stake a claim that malfunctioning code has no mistakes? Most people would take the malfunction as a sign that there is a mistake. Perhaps you meant something more like *"This code isn't working properly, but **I see** no mistakes in it."*? Not a claim by you that there are no mistakes, only that you have been unable to find them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your binary search function is

```cpp
int middle = (start+end)/2;
while(start<=end)
{
    if(arr[middle] == key)
```

You're not recalculating `middle` for each iteration, which is incorrect. It should ideally be

```cpp
int middle;
while(start<=end)
{
    middle = (start+end)/2;
    if(arr[middle] == key)
```

Comment: That’s **one** issue. The other is that binary search assumes that the data is sorted; the code here doesn’t sort the input.

Comment: For "ideally", I would expect to see the declaration of `middle` also moved inside the loop, as in `while(start<=end)
{
 int middle = (start+end)/2;`. Making the variable scope as small as needed helps prevent bugs such as, well, this one.